# Photodegradation vs photooxidation

Tags: terminology, photochemistry

I have been writing a paper about polymers being "aged" by light. Most of this aging happens because light hits atmospheric oxygen and either excites it to its singlet state or causes atmospheric water to produce hydroxyl radicals. Either way, the $\ce{^1O2}$ or the $\ce{OH^*}$ causes some sort of radical mechanism which usually ends up with the polymer chain being cleaved or some $\ce{-OOH}$ group being attached on.

Anyway, that's not the important part for this post. What I am wondering about is: Should I be describing this as photo-oxidation or photo-degradation, or is either appropriate? In reviewing my paper I've noticed I constantly flip between the two. I know what I mean, but I'm worried somebody reading this will think I mean two different processes, or complain about it.

Comment: "Oxidation" is a neutral description, and would often have a defined product. "Degradation" is unwanted, or the resulting structure is at least unimportant.

Comment: You it should add a sentence in your paper to explain that it could be one or the other or either etc depending on what you know about what is going on.